# Filtering integer field with a range

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

By default `filter :foo` where `foo` is an integer field will produce the equality filter. Are there any built-in ways to make it act just like date filter: to draw two inputs that will work like a range?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No there is no such default one, but it's very easy to create it by yourself.

please see my gist with example
https://gist.github.com/3995659

put it in initializers directory

use it like

```
 filter :id , :as => :numeric_range
```

Comment: Thank you. Also here are the CSS rules that will make this input look exactly as a date filter: https://gist.github.com/4015588

Comment: If using a later version of ActiveAdmin, change `"#{method}_gte"` and `"#{method}_lte"` to `"#{method}_gteq"` and `"#{method}_lteq"`